# I want to display the Image and it's description in text using the Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I wanted to display the Image and it's description in the single lightbox or without lightbox by clicking on the knowmore button. Can anyone help regarding this. I wanted this in HTML code.

Comment: Have you tried following the lightbox instructions?

Comment: I haven't tried it because i didn't get the lightbox for that.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: u can give an hint of the lightbox right. I have tried lot, but i didn't get so only asking here

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this decision will suit you. Good luck.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.1/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.1/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>

<body>

<a href="http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/box/box-05.jpg" data-lightbox="http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/box/box-05.jpg" data-title="My caption"> <img class="example-image" src="http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/box/box-05.jpg" style="max-width:10%;max-height:10%;" alt="image-test"/>Image test</a>
  
</body>
```